# c++ struct with bool array member. How use in main code

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, struct

```
struct thread_data
{
  int seq, packetNum;
  bool ackTally[4];
};

main:
      bool boolArray[4];
      data[j].packetNum = 3;      
      data[j].seq = 1;      
      data[j].ackTally = boolArray;
```

Running this code gives me this error

error: incompatible types in assignment of `bool [1]` to `bool [0]`

```
   data[j].ackTally = boolArray;
```

How do I resolve this in code?  (It may not be relevant by I'll probably want to change some of these values later within the main code)

Comment: What you have above doesn't compile as a standalone. Please post the actual code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: `data` is not declared anywhere. And what is `main:`? A label??

Comment: Aside from that, you cannot assign arrays in C or C++. What you wrote copies the pointer.

Comment: It is very hard to understand your question because it is not well explained. If you would have tell that the code does not compile because you are trying to copy an array and you would not have take about `bool` which has nothing to do about the fact that an array cannot be copied in C++ (misleading information) and you would have tell that it is a compilation error instead of telling that running the code give an error, it would be easier to understand you. **The only reason I was able to understand your question is by reading other comments**. Next time, put more effort in your questions!

Comment: You can also copy the whole structure or directly initialize the structure (assuming that `boolArray` is a local variable initialized in the same function as `data`). Given that you haven't provide much information, it is hard to suggest you the best way to do it in your particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C-style arrays cannot be assigned.  There are two simple ways around this:

First, use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) instead of assignment:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct thread_data
{
  int seq, packetNum;
  bool ackTally[4];
};

int main() {
    thread_data data;
    bool boolArray[4];
    // Initialize boolArray.
    std::copy( std::begin(boolArray), std::end(boolArray),
               std::begin(data.ackTally) );
}
```

Or second, replace your C-style arrays with [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).  One of several benefits of `std::array` is that it *can* be assigned:

```
#include <array>

struct thread_data
{
  int seq, packetNum;
  std::array<bool, 4> ackTally;
};

int main() {
    thread_data data;
    std::array<bool, 4> boolArray;
    // Initialize boolArray.
    thread_data.ackTally = boolArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays can not be assigned. Each element must be copied in a loop. You don't have to write that loop yourself though, since there is an algorithm for that in the standard library: `std::copy`.

P.S. Copying from `boolArray` will have undefined behaviour because its values are indeterminate.